# Change css when tab has active class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to change the background colour of the `<body>` depending on what tab specific is active.

When a tab is active, a class called 'st_view_active' is added onto the tab content. In the tab content I add a hidden div with the hex code of what my body background colour should be when that tab is active, my jQuery code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function(){
         $('body').css('backgroundColor',$('.st_view_active').find('.background').text());
     });
 });
```

And my html code when the tab is active is following:

```
<div class="tab-6 st_view st_view_active" >
   <div style="display:none" class="background">yellow</div>
   <div class="st_view_inner">
        tab 6
    </div>
</div>
```

So when tab6 is active the background of the body should be yellow. However, this is not working, the background colour is not changing, what am I doing wrong here?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yunowork/CNYDU/1/) and [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yunowork/CNYDU/1/show/)

Thanks
PS: The red and blue square is the next and previous tab handler..

Comment: It's better to include plugins through the "Add Resources" panel on the left.

Comment: Could I ask you to prune that CSS back to the *relevant* parts? I'm not convinced it's *all* needed for the purposes of your demo. Also: when posting a demo remember the concept of [SSCCE: Short, Self-Contained, Correct/Compilable Example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: For some strange reason cannot comment on depot's answer, I get this 'Cannot add comments to this post; it may be locked, deleted, or frozen' 

So will add my reply here..
--------
Thanks a lot depot, works fine, except for when I link directly to a tab or open the page the background stays white, is there a way to inherit the background colour in the hidden div upon opening the page or direct linking to a tab? http://jsfiddle.net/CNYDU/10/show/#curabitur linking to this tab the background colour is white whereas it should be green..

Comment: What plugin are you using for the tabs?

Comment: Slide Tabs: http://www.slidetabs.com/

Comment: Yunowork, I highly suggest that you take Jlange's advise and use the data attribute for the background color.  You can see a working example in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/CNYDU/25/

I put the default color at the end of `sColor`, but you could instead grab the first view and use its color. I did it this way to cut down on testing since your fiddle is painful to work with.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var hsh = window.location.hash.replace('#','');
    var sColor = hsh ? $("#slidetabs_45").find("."+hsh+" .background").text() : "#3b0";
    $("body").css("background-color", sColor);

    $("#slidetabs_45").slidetabs({
        onContentVisible:function(e){
            var color = $("#slidetabs_45").find(".st_view_active .background").text();

            $("body").css("background-color", color);
        }
    });       
});
```

I also added the `.st_view_active` class to the first view so that it will start correctly.

I also added a CSS3 transition to the background color, which isn't necessary.

Comment: Fabulous, this works almost exactly as what I wanted! With the exactly I mean that when I link directly to a tab eg. http://jsfiddle.net/CNYDU/19/show/#tab-10 the background colour will be green (tab1 is green) while the background colour property for that tab (tab-10) is set on purple. What is the reason for this?

Comment: @Yunowork probably because the active tab class isn't changing when you link directly to it.

Comment: Strange, when I inspect the element the active class is there when directly linking to a specific tab.

Comment: You sir, are a genius! Thanks a lot, learned and saw a lot of new things in here.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a great opportunity to use data elements in html. Rather than having a hidden div with the background color you want, you can simple add a `data-color` attribute to your tab `a` tag. Then when the div is clicked you can set the color easily with an event handler.

link to an updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/CNYDU/15/

Note: The next and previous tabs do not work in this example, but it should be easy to get them working, just attach a listener to each that runs

`$('body').css('background-color', $(".st_tab_active").attr('data-color'));`

as its callback.

Comment: This doesn't change the colors correctly. You have to click on the tab twice to get the correct color to show. Otherwise, it's the color of the previous "active" tab.

Comment: Works for me? Like I said the next and previous buttons aren't working in the example.

Comment: the active class isn't changed on click. it's changed after the animation is complete. So, when you change the background color on click, it's not the "current" active class, but instead the previous one.

Comment: Did you try the example? It most certainly is the right colors for the right tabs.

Comment: Ah, you changed it since last I checked.

Comment: You're looking at the above code for next and previous that I did not implement, the reason the above code would work, is because he would have to find the plugins event handlers for those tabs, and would add my line after the class is changed.

Comment: Maybe you got my first version? I edited the post before your original comment.

Comment: I probably pulled it up and noodled with it while you were updating the post.

Answer (score -1):

Check out the [livequery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery) plugin for jQuery.

> **Live Query also has the ability to fire a function (callback) *when it matches a new element and another function (callback) for when an element is no longer matched***. This provides ultimate flexibility and untold use-cases. For example the following code uses a function based Live Query to implement the jQuery hover helper method and remove it when the element is no longer matched.

Their example:

```
$('li') 
.livequery(function(){ 
// use the helper function hover to bind a mouseover and mouseout event 
    $(this) 
        .hover(function() { 
            $(this).addClass('hover'); 
        }, function() { 
            $(this).removeClass('hover'); 
        }); 
}, function() { 
    // unbind the mouseover and mouseout events 
    $(this) 
        .unbind('mouseover') 
        .unbind('mouseout'); 
});
```

You should be able to adapt this to your css changes like fired events, and therefor perform your actions based on which tab is active.

I have forked [Jlange's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13463833/908471) [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CNYDU/15/), which uses the data attribute, for a demo of how this plugin would be used:

- http://jsfiddle.net/nj6ZY/2/
- http://jsfiddle.net/nj6ZY/2/show/#tab-10  - Also works with a link to activate a specific tab

And the relevant bits:

```
$('.st_tabs_ul li a.st_tab_active').livequery(function(){ 
    $('body').css('background-color', $(this).data('color'));
});
```

Comment: Your posted code has no relevance to the question asked? Why use a plugin for something that can be done in < 5 lines of jQuery?

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding then.  As I understand it, the background should change when the active tab changes, based on the css class, not just on document load.

Comment: Yes, but that can be accomplished very easily with an even handler, no plugin necessary :)

Comment: There is an event for class changes now?  This could easily be handled in the click event on selecting the active tab, but the changing of css - as far as I knew - does not fire an event.

Comment: No, you just bind to the click event from the next tab. It doesn't matter when the class changes...

Answer (score -2):

Put ID's on your tabs. Example for id="tab6":

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   if ($('#tab6').attr('class') == 'tab-6 st_view st_view_active') {
      $('body').css('background-color', 'yellow');
   }
});
```

However, why would you attach this function to document ready only? I would bind the function to when the element is clicked...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but doesn't seem to work when I try. Could this be because of the way the plugin is written?

Comment: Try now. I was missing the closing paranthese in document ready function (happens when you write code from an iPhone:))

Comment: If you followed this method, you would have to have a listener for every single tab. Why not have one listener for all of them? Also I don't think hard coding the colors was the goal here.

Comment: So you're suggesting that he hardcode values for each tab? This is bad code.